# Numbers are distorting in Div

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a div in which numbers are squeezing when numbers are reaching more than 100 thousand like 11295551.25

```
<div  class="col-2 text-right pr-0 "><%# Eval("CreditLimit", "{0:c}").ToString().Replace(".", ".</div><div class='col-1 pl-0'>") %></div>
```

My bootstrap class is creating problem, i need to rectify that.here is booststrap col-2 which is creating problem.

```
col-2{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%;word-wrap: break-word}
```

[image: Err Snapshot]

Comment: Show us the actual HTML output, not the Razor code. It's hard to tell what you are getting here.

Comment: can you show the html output rather than the c# - see how to create a [mcve].  But most likely it's because you create another div and so they're probably overlapping if the content is too long for your flex container

Comment: This is likely a CSS issue where the two `<div>`'s are overlapping. Might consider not splitting them apart.

Comment: @GregOgle yes there is other div also but its work until 5 digit numbers with decimal but once 6th digit comes then its squeezed

Comment: @DavidG yes i am adding it now

Comment: @DavidG i have attached the image, are you guys able to open?

Comment: No, show us the raw HTML, not how the browser is rendering it.

Comment: @DavidG - i have added the snap shot again but its showing as link in question.I have added the whole Div. raw whole html page is very big.So i took the complete Div for this section where overlap is happening.

Comment: You are missing the point. We don't want to see your Razor code, we want to see the HTML that is generated from it, the stuff that the browser sees.

Comment: @DavidG  - i have updated  the generated html code

Comment: @Pete - i have added  the generated html code

Comment: It hasn't included any of the numbers - just view source of the page and copy and paste the relevant html

Comment: @Pete - Here you are...i find the numbers in generated html..pasted that DIV

Comment: You should use CSS attribute **word-break: break-word;** on your CSS class ** .col-currency** because it,s money :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS attribute **word-break** as following:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

on your CSS class **col-currency** because it,s about displaying money.

Hopefully, you will be good with this approach, let me know if it helps you out!

Comment: Let me try and come back to you

Comment: Can I add the style in DIV directly like this <div class="col-2 text-right pr-0" style"word-break: break-word;"><%# Eval("CreditLimit", "{0:c}").ToString().Replace(".", ".</div><div class='col-1 pl-0'>") %></div>

Comment: Yes as inline, if you don,t want to edit your CSS class

Comment: i tried above inline  that i mentioned in my comment but  its not working.....

Comment: If i remove existing class and use only with your style then it works otherwise inline is not working........any way to use with inline?

Comment: Inline is not then best idea, you could  update your CSS class **col-currency** with the new CSS attribute **word-break: break-word;**, then it should work. If not check out why, because something else (another CSS rule) would have overriden it. Fix it then and you should good

Comment: i just found the correct bootstrap class which creating problem , col-2{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%;word-wrap: break-word}